# Multi-store hreflang-Tag extension - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, seo

At the moment we are using two separate magento systems: One for Germany & Switzerland and one for 7 other Countries. How can we integrate the hreflang-Tag, to make sure Google is serving the correct language or regional urls in Search results (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

Because of SEO issues this is very important for us. Is there a way to map / match the two independent magento systems - e.g. by using an identifier?

Many thanks for your Ideas and Feedback. Cheers JBG

Answer (score 2):

You may check [SEO Suite Ultimate extension](http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-seo-extension.html) for Magento 2 (or [this one](http://www.mageworx.com/seo-suite-ultimate-magento-extension.html), is you are on Magento 1.9).

The extension supports hreflang tag and lets you inform Google about the alternative language version of a page.

So if you have localized pages for Germany & Switzerland and one for 7 other Countries, and want to serve Google the correct language version for each page, the extension will let you do that in a couple of clicks.

You may check the demo version of the extension here: http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-seo-extension.html